# JavaScript slideshow with function issue

Tags: javascript, html, slideshow

The function plusSlides is called in my html via onclick. [This](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp) shows the similar function and html I am using. The class `mySlides`, holds the text that will display for each `n==x`in `showSlides`. Unlike the slideshow example in the link, my function does not work when I try to click on `onclick="plusSlides(-1)"`. For instance, when I click three times on `plusSlides(-1)`, both `aerialMap` and `fedTiless` are added but `roadMap` is not. Would anyone know why?

```
function roadMap() {    
  map.addLayer(Road);
  map.removeLayer(febTiles);

}
function febTiless() {

  map.addLayer(febTiles);
  map.removeLayer(Road);

}

function aerialMap() {

  map.addLayer(Aerial);
  map.removeLayer(febTiles);
  map.removeLayer(Road);
}


var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}
function currentSlide(n) {

  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}
function showSlides(n) {

  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");

  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  if(n == 1)
   aerialMap();
  if(n == 2) 
   febTiless();
  if(n == 3)
   roadMap();

  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
}
```

Comment: Try to add `map.removeLayer(Aerial);` to the first two functions (`roadMap` and `febTiless`). Maybe the absence of these calls may have caused the layer that should be visible to be overlaid by `Aerial`.

Comment: Thank you for the comment but that does not solve the issue of the plusSlides(-1) malfunctioning when compared to the plusSlides(1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug is in this part of the code:

```
if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
if(n == 1)
  aerialMap();
if(n == 2) 
  febTiless();
if(n == 3)
  roadMap();
```

In the first two lines the *slideIndex* variable is adjusted (correctly) to cycle back into the valid range of slide numbers, but the `if` conditions that follow are still based on *n*, which has *not* been adjusted in that way, so *n* will be 0 (or 4) in some cases, and then none of the `if` conditions will be `true`.

So adjust like this:

```
var slideIndex;
showSlides(1);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex + n); // avoid assignment here
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(n); // avoid assignment here
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");

  slideIndex = n; // assign only here, at a single place
  // Don't use n anymore, only work with slideIndex
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (slideIndex < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  if(slideIndex == 1)
   aerialMap();
  if(slideIndex == 2) 
   febTiless();
  if(slideIndex == 3)
   roadMap();

  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
}
```